# How to set javadoc of external libraries in IntelliJ Idea?

Tags: intellij-idea, documentation, javadoc

In IntelliJ Idea I set offline javadoc of Java SDK in **Project structure -> SDKs -> Documentation Paths** and add path to documentation folder. Whenever I want to see tooltip I just press Ctrl + Q to see offline documentation for a symbol at caret. But it works only for Java SDK. For example - I am using servlet-api.jar library, I downloaded servlet-api javadoc, but I cannot import it to IntelliJ Idea in any way. I tried to add it to SDKs -> Documentation Paths but it didn't work. Is it a way how to import offline javadoc of other libraries to see tooltips easily?

This attempt doesn't work.
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the project type is not Maven or Gradle, adding Javadoc for particular library is done via settings in Project Structure(Ctrl + Shift + Alt + S). Add library by choosing Java from option. Then add particular JavaDoc for that library. Then choose apply. To see tooltip window not only by pressing Ctrl + Q but also by hover over symbol, choose File -> Settings -> Editor -> General -> and check Show quick documentation on mouse move.

[image: adding library]

[image: adding javadoc]

[image: before applying]

Answer (score 4):

You can load your api in the libraries of your project along with the javadocs.

Open your Project structure (Ctrl+Alt+Shift+S).
Add your library (like Servlet-api from maven)

[image]

make sure to check the JavaDocs box

[image]

Now you can use Ctrl+Q with this library.

**EDIT**:
Here is an example for info() method of the log4j library documentation Ctrl+Q:

[image: ![enter image description here]

the popup window might be resized to show content. Just drag the right bottom.
Or use the tool window for documentation with `View > Tool Window > Documentation`.

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Thank you for advice, I downloaded library from Maven with Javadocs but unfortunately the problem remains. When hovering over symbol or pressing Ctrl+Q, I can see only empty window with the name of symbol. I tried it again after restarting Idea with the same result. Is it working in your Idea?

Comment: Hi @Petr.M, see my EDIT in the answer for what I get, when I press Ctrl + Q. I use IntelliJ 2018.3.2 on an Windows 10.

Comment: Hi @hce, thanks for further information. At first adding javadoc in Project Structure window via Maven didn't help at all, but it was only because that type of my project wasn't Maven - it was Java Enterprise Web application type of project.
So I had to add in Project Structure that servlet-api jar as Java Library(not from Maven option) and then add location of javadoc on my disk to it. Then tooltip works on hover, via Ctrl + Q and also via Shift + F1(opens JavaDoc in browser).
Your solution works perfectly for Maven type projects.

Comment: Hi @Petr.M, thanks for pointing out the project type. I wouldn't thought of it.

Comment: So, I have opened a project in IDEA, and there are a bunch of dependencies in pom.xml, which were automatically added to Project Structure as plain 'Java' libs, not treated specially as a 'Maven' type. Do I really have to manually re-add them as 'Maven' libs, just to enjoy quick documentation features?

Comment: Oh, neverming. Right click on that pom.xml again, and choose `Maven | Download [Sources and ]Documentation`.

Answer (score 1):

Use Add button in [**Configure Library Dialog**](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configure-library-dialog.html) to add the documentation:
[image]